# Jasmine test for an ajax request that returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise

I am new to Angular testing.

I am trying to test a simple method in a service that gets some data via an ajax call and returns a promise using Jasmine.

So far very unsuccessfully.

This is the method I am testing:

```
function getDefaultFibonnacci() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/fibonnacci/get' })
            .success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

This is my test code: (Please note all other tests pass apart from 'should return 0,1,1,2,3'

```
describe('datacontext', function () {
    var $httpBackend;
    var $rootScope;
    var datacontext;
    var $q;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
        inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$q_, _datacontext_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            datacontext = _datacontext_;
            $q = _$q_;
        });
    });

    it('should have a getDefaultFibonnacci() function', function () {
        expect(angular.isFunction(datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci)).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should return a promise', function () {
        expect(datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci().then).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should return 0,1,1,2,3', function () {
        var sequence = '123';

        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html').respond('');
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/fibonnacci/get').respond('0,1,1,2,3');

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        promise.then(function (response) {
            sequence = response.success;
        });

        datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci().then(function (data) { deferred.resolve(data); });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(sequence).toEqual('0,1,1,2,3');
    });
});
```

Guys thanks for all your comments. I learnt a lot through this exercise.

This is the code I ended up with for a passing test.

```
function getDefaultFibonnacci() {
        return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/fibonnacci/get' });
    }

it('should return 0,1,1,2,3', function () {
        var sequence;

        $httpBackend.whenGET('app/dashboard/dashboard.html').respond('');

        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/fibonnacci/get').respond('0,1,1,2,3');

        datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci().then(function (data) {
            sequence = data.data;
        });

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(sequence).toEqual('0,1,1,2,3');
    });
```

Comment: Please consider reading about the deferred anti pattern - your code is a lot more complicated than it should be and can be greatly simplified. You have deferreds you don't actually need in your code.

Comment: Is mocha an option? It has nicer syntax than Jasmine for testing promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) has a **`flush()`** method for exactly this reason.

`flush()` simulates the http server responding, so it will trigger the resolution of your `$http.get()`. Until you call `flush()`, nothing will happen (the server hasn't responded yet).

As such, replace your `$rootScope.digest()` code with `$httpBackend.flush()` and work from there.

Furthermore, you can save a lot of effort by understanding that `$http` methods themselves return promises.

This:

```
function getDefaultFibonnacci() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/fibonnacci/get' })
        .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            deferred.reject(status);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
function getDefaultFibonnacci() {

    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/fibonnacci/get' })

}
```

And will do the same thing.

Finally you don't need another promise in your test. This is enough (remove all reference to `$q` and deferred and put this directly after your `$httpBackend.when(...` code):

```
datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci()
.then(function (data) { 
    sequence = data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am still getting my head around Angular/JS. I was not aware $http returns a promise. Changing the code as you suggests results in data being a json blob containing amongst other things an attribute called data containing my string. Is this what you expected or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jemmitch that is expected - if you want it explicitly you can do: `return $http(...).then(function(response){ return response.data; })`

Comment: Changed to this pattern. I will do some investigation on $http (and it has been suggested i switch to restangular) as this lacks error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting an object {success: "0,1,1,2,3"} as the response from the http service? You're using `response.success` when promise resolved

```
promise.then(function (response) {
            sequence = response.success;
        });
```

whereas you're returning a string '0,1,1,2,3'

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/fibonnacci/get').respond('0,1,1,2,3');
```

Also, from the code I see that you don't need to create another promise to test your method.

Try this:

```
it('should return 0,1,1,2,3', function () {
        var sequence = '123';

        $httpBackend.when('GET', 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html').respond('');
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/fibonnacci/get').respond('0,1,1,2,3');

        datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci().then(function (data) { sequence = data; });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(sequence).toEqual('0,1,1,2,3');
    });
```

Comment: Even if you call `$rootScope.$digest` it would really surprise me if sequence would be initialized right away. If it does - it's definitely a bug. Can you create a fiddle illustrating this behavior?

Comment: Do you mean it should instead use $httpBacked.flush() rather than $rootScope.$digest() or it's not the expected behavior of $rootScope.$digest() to resolve a promise?

Comment: Even resolved promises defer their execution to the next cycle. This is part of the Promises/A+ spec the test should be asynchronous.

Comment: Okay!! so, would it work if the promise has already been resolved before calling $digest()?

Comment: I hope not. That's a big point of the A+ spec :) Imagine that it would _sometimes_ run and sometimes wouldn't run - that's indeterminism through a race condition which is a very bad thing you don't want to have in your code :)

Comment: Response.Success is a mistake and I changed it to just look at Response. I got the test working (i added the flush on httpbackend and changed response.success to response) but clearly I am over complicated this code/test so I am refactoring based on the commments.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, So, checking whether a promise is resolved should always be done asynchronously even in unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

The most important think you forgot to do is call `$httpBackend.flush()` at some point after making the requests before using the data.

Also you don't need to create an extra promise.

```
it('should return 0,1,1,2,3', function () {
    var sequence;

    // Use the shorthand method whenGET
    $httpBackend.whenGET('app/dashboard/dashboard.html').respond('');

    // We should probably test that this request is actually made, so use expect<method>
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/fibonnacci/get').respond('0,1,1,2,3');

    // Leave out the extra promise code.
    // var deferred = $q.defer();
    // var promise = deferred.promise;

    // promise.then(function (response) {
    //     sequence = response.success;
    // });

    // datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci().then(function (data) { deferred.resolve(data); });

    datacontext.getDefaultFibonnacci().then(function (response) {
        sequence = response.success;
    });

    $httpBackend.flush(); // Flush the backend. Important!
    // $rootScope.$digest(); // I don't think this is necessary.

    expect(sequence).toEqual('0,1,1,2,3');
});
```

The html template won't be called if you set up your app